# Trying to extract data from JSON or JSONP using WOT api

Tags: java, javascript, android, json, jsonp

I was using WOT(web of trust) api.In this, i am getting response in this format,

```
process( { 
    "www.google.com": {
        "target": "google.com", 
        "0": [ 95, 84 ], 
        "1": [ 95, 84 ], 
        "2": [ 95, 84 ], 
        "4": [ 93, 78 ], 
        "categories": {
            "501": 92
        } 
    }
} )
```

I am very confused to extract the data string from this format of JSON. I searched a lot but could not find any way.

I want to extract from categories... means I want to save '502' value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** JSON Objects starts with "{" and ends with "}", the response you're getting is not a correct JSON Format.

**Analysis :** Why? you might ask, the response started with `p` char from `process`, and ends with `)` char, instead of "}".

**Solution :** To fix the json, we will need to remove the `process (` and `)` string, so that the response can be parsed as JSON.

**Hint :** Use `String.replace()` method to replace the unwanted string with empty string `""`, more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Hope this helps, and Good Luck! ^^

Reid